# MVC 5 routing issue with new url for subcategories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-2, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In my productcontroller I have two actionresult returning methods:

```
[Route("Shop/{brand}/{category}/{subcategory?}/{page:int?}")]
public ActionResult Index(string brand, string category, string subcategory, int? page, SortOptions currentSort = SortOptions.SinceDesc)
{ //...
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Shop/{brand}/{category}/{subcategory?}/{page:int?}")]
public ActionResult Index(ProductsViewModel pvm)
{ //...
```

And this is my razor view:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SubCatID, Model.SubCategoriesSelectList, new { @class = "multiselect" })
}
```

When I submit the page it hits the httppost method but the url is still: Shop/nike/shoes even when I selected the subcategory runningshoes from the dropdown.
I would like to have urls like:

- shop/nike/shoes
- shop/nike/shoes/runningshoes

Being more of a webform-guy I am having a hard time to navigate to new url's and using viewmodel properties as parameters.

**edit** posted my UI:
[image]
to explain my ui:

the first dropdown should `get` to a subcategory. for instance: shop/nike/shoes/runningshoes

The second should post 'back' to sort the products.

The price slider should post back because it should filter. (would filter client side if there was no paging)

The paging should get so you can deeplink to a certain page: shop/nike/shoes/runningshoes/page2 etc.

Comment: Form values are not reflected in the route (fortunately). If you want that url based on the selected subcategory, you need to redirect to the GET method (passing the parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BeginForm(...)` you end up having to pass a route values dictionary with `Subcategory = "runningshoes"`

This does mix  values being passed by GET, aka in the querystring through the route values dictionary, and POST, which will be the values from the form, but will accomplish what you are trying to do.  More can be read about the `BeginForm(..)` overload [Here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933(v=vs.118).aspx)

You should end up with:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", new { subcategory = "runningshoes" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SubCatID, Model.SubCategoriesSelectList, new { @class = "multiselect" })
}
```

**EDIT**

Just realized you want the value from the form post to be in the QueryString on the response.  Instead of returning the view directly from your MVC method for the Form Post what you could possibly do is a `return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { subcategory = request.SubCategory });` which you would have an action that would support this redirect specifically.

Additional information on redirect to action can be found [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Ok but I have multiple dropdowns and other options. So I need a form for everyone of them? for instance 4 times `<form ...></form` on a page? The subcategory parameter should be the selected value of the dropdownlist. I hope that you understand me :) thanks for your time though!

Comment: If you would like you can use the above RedirectToAction edit and have only a single form.  You could null check the different options and redirect accordingly building out your full URL you would in the end like to have.  The reason you are not seeing the subcategory in your URL now is you are sending the value via POST which sends it in the request body instead of the query string.  MVC supports the RouteValue dictionary (or from anonymous object route values) to change the URL given a route definition.  I hope this helps, if not feel free to clarify and I'll do my best.

Comment: Oooooor another idea would be to do away with the form post entirely and just use a Form.GET.  If this is more for navigation purposes you would want the features of a GET more than a POST anyway.  I edited my answer to give you some options.  Any questions, please ask!

Comment: Thank you, updated the question with the UI and the actions I try to build in it. Would like to know what the best approach would be.

Comment: The path I would choose would either be the RedirectToAction approach or using the FormMethod.GET to wire to the route.  I know 100% that the RedirectToAction approach would work, and I'm fairly certain the FormMethod.GET instead of POST should work as well.  From there it's up to you.  Both are equally correct solutions.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I could keep the form to post so that I can see the new value of the dropdownlist and then redirecttoaction (which is a get) to get the nice url? Because when I switch the formmethod to get, it does not fill the subcategory parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77004/discussion-between-jp-hellemons-and-vulgarbinary).